# Segmentation fault (core dumped) Laravel SwiftMailer

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, swiftmailer

I'm having problem when using SwiftMailer Laravel 5.2. I have a controller for sending email and I set it to run every minute. When I execute my script below with php artisan schedule:run, its keeps return an error message 'Segmentation fault (core dumped)'.

My script:

```
public static function sendMailCoc()
{
    $mail_log = MailLog::where('status', '!=', 'SENT')->where('type', '3')->orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
    foreach($mail_log as $mail){
        if($mail->to!='') {
            $coc = json_decode($mail->parameter, true);
            try {
                Mail::queue($mail->file_view,
                    ['to' => $mail->to_name,
                        'coc' => $coc,
                        'notif_id' => $mail->notification_id
                    ],
                    function ($message) use ($mail) {
                        $message->to($mail->to)
                            ->subject($mail->subject);
                    });
                $mail->status = 'SENT';
                $mail->error_message = '';
                $mail->save();
            }
            catch(Swift_TransportException $e){
                $mail->status = 'ERROR';
                $mail->error_message = $e->getMessage();
                $mail->save();
                continue;
            }catch (Exception $e) {
                $mail->status = 'ERROR';
                $mail->error_message = $e->getMessage();
                $mail->save();
                continue;
            }                    

        }
    }
}
```

Sometimes if I test to send just one email, it works and not return an error message. But when I try to send a lot of email with looping, its always get an error message "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". I'm using Ubuntu Server 14.04.

I don't know what is causing this error. It is my script that causing this problem, Laravel, or Ubuntu Linux?

Is there any way to solve this problem? What should I check first?

Thank you for your help and answer.

Comment: Getting same issue, can someone please help

Answer (score 0):

Wild shot, but I've been debugging the same error message in relation to queued jobs recently:

As per Laravel 5.6 documentation (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues#creating-jobs):

> "Binary data, such as raw image contents, should be passed through the
>   base64_encode function before being passed to a queued job. Otherwise,
>   the job may not properly serialize to JSON when being placed on the
>   queue."

My problem was resolved (almost!) as soon as I added `base64_encode($input)` in constructor and `base64_decode($this->input)` in handle() function.

PS: Since I was using two distributed apps for input and working on the queue, I also had to run `composer dump-autoload` and `php artisan cache:clear` on both apps, while also restarting the `supervisor` worker, after making the code change.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My email does not contain any binary data such as image or something. But I still follow your instruction for encode the email first before sending. Unfortunately it still not working.

Comment: After some another researching, I finally found the reason why SwiftMailer stop working and show error segmentation fault. It because the email address recipient is not valid or not exist, and the SwiftMailer Error Exception doesn't catch the error or timeout. Do you have any idea how to make exception handling SwiftMailer properly? I have try all Error Exception but it still not working.

Answer (score 0):

`Mailable` can have `implements ShouldQueue` on your class.

Then you pass parameters to `__construct` and you save it in your class.

Like this:

```
public function __construct(Sale $sale)
{
    $this->sale         = $sale->withoutRelations();
...
```

BUT if you forget `withoutRelations()` function, the system will `Serialize` your object with links that will be lost after you `UnSerialize` your data back. That would cause the message

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Simple test that show you that Queue is at fault if to disable it for testing.
For that go to `phpunit.xml` file and change

```
<env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
```

to

```
<env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="null"/>
```